# PostgreSQL denies change in table ownership

Tags: postgresql, permissions

I am trying to change the ownership of a table for which I am already the owner.
I am also the owner of the database and have the CREATE and USAGE privileges on the PUBLIC schema.
I get the following error message:

```
ts_d=> ALTER TABLE table1 OWNER TO user2;
ERROR:  permission denied for schema public
```

How to change ownership without logging as superuser?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must be a member of both the old and the new owning role, and the target role needs the  `CREATE` privilege on the schema.

Comment: CREATE privilege on the schema for the target role was the culprit, it now works, many thanks!

Comment: @SébastienClément If that answer solved your question then you should [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it, so that your question is marked as resolved.